# Как определить физический размер БД и одной конкретной таблицы?

Tags: java, php, sql-server, mysql

Здравствуйте. Как средствами `PHP` и средствами `Java`, определить занимаемый физический (на диске, в байтах или килобайтах, без разницы) размер базы данных и занимаемый размер одной таблицы? Интересует `MySql` для `PHP` и `Microsoft SQL Server 2000` (и более поздние версии) для `Java`. 
**PS:**
Два вопроса, касающихся реализации на двух разных ЯП.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mysql**

```
SELECT    DATA_FREE
    FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'bd_name'
    AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'table_name';
//для всей базы
SELECT    SUM(DATA_FREE)
    FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'bd_name'
```

**MS SQL**
по идее так, но не проверял

```
DBCC UPDATEUSAGE (0);
CREATE TABLE #t([имя таблицы] varchar(255), [строк] varchar(255), [зарезервировано] varchar(255), [всего данных] varchar(255), [размер индексов] varchar(255), [свободно] varchar(255));
INSERT INTO #t
exec sp_msforeachtable N'exec sp_spaceused ''?''';
SELECT * FROM #t ORDER BY CONVERT(bigint, REPLACE([всего данных], ' KB', '')) DESC;
DROP TABLE #t;
```